# how upgrade perf and minimize main thread work next/Dynamic

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I got optimization question about SEO & Performance, as a lot of us I'm challenging my selft to have the best score on the lighthouse to have the best chance to raise in the google index. So I reduce a lot of my assets, use module.css but even if my score is over 95 on desktop my mobile score is only over 75/60 ​​points ...

I found to way to increase the performance, I noticed the request number is a bit to hight, 105 requests:

[image]

So it’s follows that’s following warning:

[image]

Which is impact the FCP and the LCP, So I look at about kind of solution to split the code and call it when the are required (lazy load). So next / Dynamic from next should be the solution but I’m a bit confused because I don’t know exactly how to use it, I mean:

-What is the good case to import component with or without next / Dynamic?

-Will I get worse if I abuse of it?

-Should I use AMP?

Comment: Are you using SSG or SSR ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it I use SSR